# positive lookahead regex R

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying a regex lookahead in R with the following command:

```
 sub(x = street.addresses, pattern = "\\s((?i)Street|(?i)St\\.?)(?=\\sNE)", replacement = " St")
```

My goal is to replace Street with St where it's followed by a space and the directional NE (as in, "Northeast"). It seems like the lookahead couldn't be more straightforward but I keep hitting an error:

```
Error in sub(x = streets, pattern = "\\s((?i)Street|(?i)St\\.?)(?=\\sNE)",: 
invalid regular expression '\s((?i)Street|(?i)St\.?)(?=\sNE)', reason 
'Invalid regexp'
```

Versions of this without the lookahead work fine in R, but as soon as I add a lookahead of any sort to my search/replace, I hit the error. Likewise, other regex R functions like grep seem to have the same problem.

I've copied/pasted that regex expression into engines like https://regex101.com/ and it seems to work fine there, so I'm confused. Am I missing something basic about regex in R?

EDIT:

Here's a copy direct from my console:

```
> street.addresses <- c("23 Charles Street NE","23 Charles St. NE")
> new.vec <- sub(x = street.addresses, pattern = "\\s((?i)Street|(?i)St\\.?)
(?=\\sNE)", replacement = " St")
Error in sub(x = street.addresses, pattern = "\\s((?i)Street|(?i)St\\.?)(?
=\\sNE)",  : 
invalid regular expression '\s((?i)Street|(?i)St\.?)(?=\sNE)', reason 
'Invalid regexp'
```

Comment: You should include a sample input vector and the appropriate output [to make your example reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/ddg#5963610)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `sub` in Perl mode if you want to use a lookahead:

```
street <- "123 Hudson Street NE, New York, NY"
sub(x = street, pattern = "\\s((?i)Street|(?i)St\\.?)(?=\\sNE)",
    replacement = " St", perl=TRUE)

[1] "123 Hudson St NE, New York, NY"
```

### Demo

By the way, if you put the parameters to `sub` in their default positions, then you can omit the names, leaving us with a more terse call:

```
sub("\\s((?i)Street|(?i)St\\.?)(?=\\sNE)", " St", street, perl=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you do not need a positive lookahead if the blow is what you want:

```
street = c("2389 E. Myronga Street NE")
sub(x = street, pattern = "\\s((?i)Street|(?i)St\\.?)\\sNE", replacement = " St")
```

Output:

> sub(x = street, pattern = "\s((?i)Street|(?i)St\.?)\sNE", replacement = " St")
>   [1](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/regex) "2389 E. Myronga St NE"

However, you can use a positive lookaround (and other Perl compatible regex (PCRE) functionality) if you set `PERL=TRUE` as additional argument

```
sub(x = street, pattern = "\\s((?i)Street|(?i)St\\.?)(?=\\sNE)", replacement = " St", perl=TRUE)
```

The reason for this difference is, there are two types of regular expressions used in R, extended regular expressions (the default) and Perl-like regular expressions used by `perl = TRUE` ([R doc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/regex), see also [regular-expressions.info/rlanguage](https://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html)).

Comment: Hmmm, it works but I don't know *how*. How does the function know I don't want to replace \sNE with my replacement string as well as the rest of the matching expression?

Comment: It's indeed confusion. I have added more context to explain this.

Comment: @Brandon the core of this expression is `\\s(Street|St)\\sNE`. `Street|St` is in a capturing group, and we're just replacing the capture group with "St". `(?i)` just means "case insensitive", so "street/Street" will both be matched.