# extract until next "_" if contains

Tags: r, gsub

Is there a way to extract part of string, when there is a match (everything up to the next underscore) "_"?

From: `mycampaign_s22uhd4k_otherinfo`  I need: `s22uhd4k`.
From: `my_campaign_otherinfo_s22jumpto_otherinfo`  , I would need: `s22jumpto`

data:

```
df <- structure(list(a = c("mycampaign_s22uhd4k_otherinfo", "my_campaign_otherinfo_s22jumpto_otherinfo"
), b = c(1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Not completely clear what the logic is.  In the first example the second element is being extracted, in the other the third.  Do they always begin with `s22` or are they always second from the end?

Comment: It's difficult to work out the 'rule'; is it the second last 'group' that you want to capture? E.g. does this make sense? `gsub(df$a, pattern = ".*_(.*)_.*", replacement = "\\1", perl = TRUE)` (output: [1] "s22uhd4k"  "s22jumpto")

Comment: @RitchieSacramento not always beging with `s22` but for simplicity I put it that way... the thing is that they're not always be in the same position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Omar, based on your update/comment, this regex will solve your problem:

```r
df <- structure(list(a = c("mycampaign_s22uhd4k_otherinfo",
                           "my_campaign_otherinfo_s22jumpto_otherinfo",
                           "e220041_pe_mx_aon_aonjulio_conversion_shop_facebook-network_ppl_primaria_s22test512gb_hotsale_20220620"
), b = c(1, 2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

gsub(df$a, pattern = ".*(s22[^_]+(?=_)).*", replacement = "\\1", perl = TRUE)
#> [1] "s22uhd4k"     "s22jumpto"    "s22test512gb"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Explanation:

`.*(s22[^_]+(?=_)).*`

`.*`  match all characters up until the first capture group

`(s22` the first capture group starts with "s22"

`[^_]+` after "s22", match any character except "_"

`(?=_)` until the next "_" ([positive look ahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133979/positive-lookahead-regex-r))

`)` close the first capture group

`.*` match all remaining characters

Then, the `replacement = "\\1"` means to just print the captured text (the part you want)

Comment: Both work, but second option is safer as you condition it to start with "s22". How does the first option capture the s22 part? 

Why does it not capture: `otherinfo` ?

Comment: hi Jared, why this won't work: 

´test <- "e220041_pe_mx_aon_aonjulio_conversion_shop_facebook-network_ppl_primaria_s22test512gb_hotsale_20220620"´

gsub(test, pattern = ".*(s22.*)_.*", replacement = "\\1", perl = TRUE)

It's returning: s22test512gb_hotsale

Comment: Thanks for the update @OmarGonzales, I have edited my answer and added an explanation for how the regex is capturing the text. If this doesn't work with your actual data, please edit your question and I'll have another look at it.